# Is there a keyboard shortcut in Outlook to revert back to the default font?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2010

In Outlook when writing an email, sometimes the font changes (eg due to copy/pasting from somewhere else). In Word you can revert back to the default font by pressing Ctrl+SPACE. However, in Outlook this changes the font to Times Roman which is not the default Outlook font.

(I know you can use Format Painter but I'd prefer a keyboard shortcut.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Problem solved in Outlook 2010 (Ctrl+SPACE works). Finally!

Comment: Works like that in 2003 too.

Comment: Just broken in 2007 then?

Comment: Works in Outlook 2016.

Comment: In Outlook 365 16.0.13530.20418 Ctrl+Space does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows application Outlook 365 16.0.13530.20418 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> does not work but this shortcut works:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-for-outlook-3cdeb221-7ae5-4c1d-8c1d-9e63216c1efd#bkmk_formattext